# Количество дочерних элементов SCSS

Tags: html, веб-программирование, dom, sass, scss

Есть `div`  с некоторым количеством вложенных элементов `p`:

```html
<div>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Можно ли используя *только SCSS/SASS* как-то узнать количество вложенных в `div` элементов? Т.е нужно в некую SCSS переменную записать это количество (для примера выше `$foo: 3;`). Подойдут даже самые костыльные решения, просто интересно, как это можно сделать. В официальной ТД ничего на эту тему не нашел.

Comment: Никак, CSS не знает сколько их будет\есть.

Comment: "XY Problem" detected.

Comment: @UModeL, я понимаю, что нужно юзать js. Мне было интересно, можно ли сделать это на чистом scss

Comment: @DanSazonov: Вы не поняли на что я Вам намекнул. Есть входные данные и выходные. Исходя из них, выбирается метод и строится алгоритм решения. У Вас же, вопрос звучит, как просто "нужен алгоритм". Т.е. не ясно из чего и для чего.

Comment: @UModeL, спасибо за уточнение, поправил. Впрочем, вопрос уже решен

Answer (score -1):

```
div:has(p:nth-of-type(1):nth-last-of-type(1)) {--foo: 1}
div:has(p:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(1)) {--foo: 2}
div:has(p:nth-of-type(3):nth-last-of-type(1)) {--foo: 3}
div:has(p:nth-of-type(4):nth-last-of-type(1)) {--foo: 4}
div:has(p:nth-of-type(5):nth-last-of-type(1)) {--foo: 5}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]